# ul is applying styles but from where?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm having trouble to find the reason why a class named `nav` in `ul` element is applying styles.

I'm using the `nav` element to directly style it (without using classes). Then I gave my `ul` element a class named `nav` and is applying styles (but from where?).

I had to give my `ul` a `margin: 0` and it still have some left `padding`, where are these styles coming from?

I'm not too experienced with css and I'd appreciate the help.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/dzbm1qsd/) is where I reproduced it

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
}
/* HEADER */

header {
  min-height: 750px;
  background: url(https://static.inmopaco.tk/images/banner2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
/* top bar menu */

.top-menu {
  background: rgba(78, 197, 241, 0.81);
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
/* nav links */

nav {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 2.2em 0 0;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  min-height: 50px;
}
nav:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
nav ul > li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
  color: #000;
  background: none;
}
nav ul li a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  color: transparent;
  content: '.';
  text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover::before,
nav ul li a:focus::before,
nav ul li a.active::before {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 10px 0 #000, -10px 0 #000;
}
/* logo */

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 7px -90px 0;
}
.logo img {
  width: 75%;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:before,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
nav:before,
nav:after,
.nav:before,
.nav:after,
.navbar:before,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:before,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:before,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:before,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:before,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
nav:after,
.nav:after,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top-menu">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a class="home active">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="services scroll">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="aboutus">Sobre Nosotros</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a class="logo">
        <img src="//static.inmopaco.tk/images/logo.png">
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a class="home">Inscripción</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="services">Acceso</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: `ul`'s have padding-left by default, in the browser styles

Comment: Learn how to use your browser's dev tools - using those it is easy to find out where styles "come from" (and in this case it would have told you that the padding comes from the browser's default stylesheet.)

Comment: I'm using the dev tools but I can't find where it says that it comes from the browser's default stylesheet. I'm using firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` by default has `margin` and `padding`, and you only reset the `margin`, you have to reset `padding` as well

---

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
}
/* HEADER */

header {
  min-height: 750px;
  background: url(https://static.inmopaco.tk/images/banner2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
/* top bar menu */

.top-menu {
  background: rgba(78, 197, 241, 0.81);
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
/* nav links */

nav {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 2.2em 0 0;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  min-height: 50px;
}
nav:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
nav ul > li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
  color: #000;
  background: none;
}
nav ul li a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  color: transparent;
  content: '.';
  text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover::before,
nav ul li a:focus::before,
nav ul li a.active::before {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 10px 0 #000, -10px 0 #000;
}
/* logo */

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 7px -90px 0;
}
.logo img {
  width: 75%;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:before,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
nav:before,
nav:after,
.nav:before,
.nav:after,
.navbar:before,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:before,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:before,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:before,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:before,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
nav:after,
.nav:after,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-menu">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="home active">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="services scroll">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="aboutus">Sobre Nosotros</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="logo">
      <img src="//static.inmopaco.tk/images/logo.png">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="home">Inscripción</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="services">Acceso</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```